# How to rearrange tabs with the keyboard in Chrome on macOS?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, keyboard

I have to use a Mac at work and I can't figure out how to rearrange Chrome tabs on macOS. On Windows/Linux you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> and I can't seem to find anything about it online for Mac.

NB: I'm on an azerty keyboard, so I can't use <kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: You mean change the order of the tabs, or just make a different one front-most? Hmm... interesting [yet irritating] Safari you can use **either** Cmd/Shift [ ] **or** Cmd/Shift  ←  →. Chrome only accepts [ ]

Comment: How to change the order, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1X3geKtF8A

Comment: That's an extension. It can't do it natively.

Comment: Another solution with an extension -- [Vimium](https://vimium.github.io) is `<<` to move the tab left or `>>` to move it right

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the *Rearrange Tabs* chrome extension. Chrome on macOS doesn't natively support this functionality. It does, however, have the APIs that support this functionality. Hence, I built the extension to have this functionality. It's pretty light weight and doesn't request for any extra permissions. The link is posted in an answer down below by the user - *BitFunny*

Answer (score 12):

On Mac, Page Up and Page down are <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> respectively. So if you want to move a tab left or right without downloading an extension then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> respectively.

It might seem like a lot of buttons but the finger arrangement makes it feel very easy to press the three buttons on the bottom left at once. If you wish, you can actually just press the common center with one finger (top of finger in the bottom middle of <kbd>Shift</kbd>, bottom of finger on the other two) then use the other finger for the arrows.

Answer (score 5):

This Chrome extension works:
Rearrange Tabs
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rearrange-tabs/ccnnhhnmpoffieppjjkhdakcoejcpbga?hl=en-US

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Bloke

Vimium for Chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb

```
<<      Move tab to the left
>>      Move tab to the right



    Manipulating tabs
t       Create new tab
J, gT       Go one tab left
K, gt       Go one tab right
^       Go to previously-visited tab
g0      Go to the first tab
g$      Go to the last tab
yt      Duplicate current tab
<a-p>       Pin or unpin current tab
<a-m>       Mute or unmute current tab
x       Close current tab
X       Restore closed tab
W       Move tab to new window
<<      Move tab to the left
>>      Move tab to the right
```

Comment: If using your own key mappings, `map << moveTabLeft` and `map >> moveTabRight` will map these shortcuts for you.